# OctoberCMS plugin SEO Meta Og image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, so I thought its best to ask the community.

So my problem is this, I'm trying to share a post. The post is generated dynamically. I'm using the addthis.com sharing toolbox. I also installed the SEO plugin by netsti and added the component on header

Now when I want to share, the image doesn't load on first share. I need to scrape the information through Facebook debugger.

I want to know if there is anyway to make a

So I'd like to know if there's anyway to set up the meta og image on head with functions like onStart or onEnd

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes why not you can add your own tags in layouts.

In your layout files or partial files where your `<head>` tag is, you can define something like this

```
    {% if fbImage %}
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ fbImage }}" />            
    {% endif %}
```

Now in your page code section, you can define **onStart** method and add your **fbImage**

```
function onStart(){    

    // or you can get file object from your post or record 
    // and get its absolute path and use it `getPath()`
    $imagePath = 'https://yoursite/image.jpeg';
    $this['fbImage'] = $imagePath; // image absolute path
}
```

In this way you are telling page what image to display in **"og:image"** tag and for security we are checking its value if its not defined or blank we used if condition so **"og:image"** tag will not added.

If any issue please comment.